# how to open port 80 on box managed with Puppet

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I have a puppet master virtual machine that manages almost 20 nodes. I have Nagios installed on one of these nodes and in order for the Nagios GUI to work I would need to stop the iptables on that nagios box. The problem is that whenever Puppet runs it will start the iptables service back on.
I've tried adding a service in nagios modules server.pp file like this which didn't work. It says that the iptables service is already defined and cannot have duplicate:

```
service
   {
     iptables:
     ensure => stopped,

 }
```

Also, I've tried using an exec command

```
exec { "open-port-80":
         command  => "sudo iptables -I INPUT 14 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT",
        path     => "${os_path}",
        unless   => "sudo iptables-save | grep 80 | grep INPUT | grep ACCEPT | grep NEW | wc -l | xargs test 1 -eq",
        notify   => Exec["ip-tables-save"]
}

exec { "ip-tables-save":
         command     => "sudo service iptables save",
#        refreshonly => true,
#        path        => "${os_path}",
}
```

Also tried the code below but had no luck:

```
if defined("iptables") and defined(Class['iptables'])
  {
    iptables::add_tcp_stateful_listen
    {
      ‘nagios-core':
      client_nets => '[nagios node IP address here]/32',
        dports => ‘80',
    }
  }
```

Can someone please help me with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "service already defined" means that iptables service is defined somewhere else in the configuration. I suggest to try to find it in the existing puppet conf files and then edit it there. :)

Comment: Thanks EEAA, I'm new to Puppet and this is my first project! I have puppet installed inside /etc/puppet directory and not sure which file needs to be modified and how. Could you please help me?

Comment: well, for searching lots of configuration, use something like `grep -ri iptables /etc/puppet/` :)

Comment: 1) There are bunch of files under /etc/puppet/modules/iptables/manifests directory:

-rw-r-----. 1 root puppet 2409 Mar 22  2013 add_all_listen.pp
-rw-r-----. 1 root puppet 2650 Mar 22  2013 add_icmp_listen.pp
-rw-r-----. 1 root puppet 2674 Mar 22  2013 add_rules.pp
-rw-r-----. 1 root puppet 2902 Mar 22  2013 add_tcp_stateful_listen.pp
-rw-r-----. 1 root puppet 2776 Mar 22  2013 add_udp_listen.pp
-rw-r-----. 1 root puppet 5849 Mar 22  2013 init.pp

I’m guessing we can add a rule in there so that it lets Nagios GUI to open that port for Nagios

Comment: Or we might be able to add something like this: This is a format I found, might be able to use this, customized it and it didn't work:
 iptables::add_tcp_stateful_listen { 'open_ports':
    client_nets => "0.0.0.0/0",
    dports      => ["$conf_port"],
  }
And this is the default_all file: /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/default_all.pp

if defined (Class['iptables']) {
    iptables::add_rules { 'default_mcast' :
      header  => 'true',
      content => '-d 224.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT',
      order   => "11",
    }

Comment: When I run iptables –L on the nagios server I get an output that has these lines:

ACCEPT     udp  --  192.35.0.0/16        anywhere            state NEW multiport dports 8649

ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.35.0.0/16        anywhere            state NEW tcp multiport dports 8649


I think the info comes from a csv file here:
vi /etc/puppet/manifests/extdata/simp_def.csv
In which there is a line that reads:

# The client networks that you will be managing.
client_nets,"192.35.0.0/16"

And the Nagios server IP is 192.35.31.55

Comment: I would probably edit add_tcp_statefull_listen.pp and add:
`iptables::add_tcp_stateful_listen { 'open_ports': client_nets => "0.0.0.0/0", dports => ["80"], }`. I dont have a puppet installed to try it but that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of turning off iptables completely, I'd recommend using the Puppetlabs Firewall module to manage firewalls/iptables:

$ puppet module install puppetlabs-firewall

Then you can write some Puppet such as this:

```
firewall { '100 Allow http and https access':
  port   => [80, 443],
  proto  => tcp,
  action => accept,
}
```